# How to split large file and write into individual record using identical pattern perl?

Tags: perl, split, pattern-matching

I have a multi-GB file consisting of thousands of individual files based on their IDs.

Each component file consists of four comment lines followed by the contents. Every second commented lines has a unique ID. I would like to split the file individual files named by their ID.

There is a second `size list` of IDs and size. I want to have this line written first as the very first line in each output file.

Examples

#### size list

```
A_1 100
Bxx_xx  25
P_b 342
1A_Z0   343
Z867    200
BWS 111
```

#### input file

```
# ver XX
# Query: A_1
# Database: XX
# Usage: XX
A_1 .*
A_1 .*
A_1 .*
A_1 .*
A_1 .*
# ver
# Query: Bxx_xx
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
# ver
# Query: P_b
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
P_b.*
P_b.*
P_b.*
P_b.*
P_b.*
P_b.*
# ver
# Query: 1A_Z0
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
1A_Z0.*
1A_Z0.*
1A_Z0.*
1A_Z0.*
# ver
# Query: Z867
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
# ver
# Query: BWS
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
BWS.*
BWS.*
BWS.*
```

Output should be like this, (ID.txt)

#### A_1.txt

```
A_1 100
# ver XX
# Query: A_1
# Database: XX
# Usage: XX
A_1 .*
A_1 .*
A_1 .*
A_1 .*
A_1 .*
```

#### Bxx_xx.txt

```
Bxx_xx  25
# ver
# Query: Bxx_xx
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
Bxx_xx  .*
```

#### P_b.txt

```
P_b 342
# ver
# Query: P_b
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
P_b.*
P_b.*
P_b.*
P_b.*
P_b.*
P_b.*
```

#### 1A_Z0.txt

```
1A_Z0   343
# ver
# Query: 1A_Z0
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
1A_Z0.*
1A_Z0.*
1A_Z0.*
1A_Z0.*
```

#### Z867.txt

```
Z867    200
# ver
# Query: Z867
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
```

#### BWS.txt

```
BWS 200
# ver
# Query: BWS
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
BWS.*
BWS.*
BWS.*
```

In some cases, there may be no contents after four lines. Example,

```
# ver
# Query: Z867
# Database: XXXXXX
# Usage: XXXXX
```

Still I want them as new file, `Z867.txt`

My code is as follows

```
while ( $line = <BOF> ) {

    chomp $line;
    $cpline = $line;

    next if ( $cpline =~ /^Query/ );

    if ( $cpline =~ /^#\sQuery\:\s(\w.*)/ ) {

        $query = $1;

        foreach $sizeLine (@sizeList) {

            $sizeLine =~ /^(\w.*)\t(\d+)$/;
            $seqId  = $1;
            $seqLen = $2;

            if ( $seqId eq $query ) {
                print "Query\t$seqLen\n";
            }
        }
    }

    $cpline = "";

    if ( $line =~ /^#/ ) {
        print "$line\n";
    }

    if ( $line !~ /^#/ ) {

        if ( $line =~ /^((.+)\_.+)\t((.+)\_.+)\t(.+)\t(.+)\t.+\t.+\t.+\t.+\t.+\t.+\t.+\t\s?.+$/ ) {

            $queryId = $1;

            if ( $seqId eq $queryId ) {
                print "$line\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Go on, have a go at solving it yourself, and then asking when you hit problems.

Comment: You say *"I would like to get them into individual files followed by the contents"* so I edited your question to reflect that. But you changed it to show all of the output in a single file. Which is it, please?

Comment: Because its my first time here, I don't know how to use use all options. I am beginner in both perl and to this forum. Could someone please have a look at my code and correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes please, my edit went failed somehow. But you are right Borodin.  I  would like to get them into individual files followed by the contents.

Comment: Your code seems to have little to do with the problem you are asking about. What is `@sizeList`? It isn't defined anywhere. And the output `print "Query\t$seqLen\n"` isn't reflected in your question at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am confused about what you are asking, as your Perl code seems to do something very different from what your question describes. However, here's a simple solution that opens a new file for every `# Query:` line in the comment and generates the output that you say you want

This program expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my $out_fh;
my @header;

while ( <> ) {

    if ( /^#/ ) {

        push @header, $_;

        if ( /Query:\s*(\S+)/ ) {
            my $file = "$1.txt";
            print qq{Creating "$file"\n};
            open $out_fh, '>', $file;
        }

        if ( @header == 4 ) {
            print $out_fh @header;
            @header = ();
        }
    }
    elsif ( $out_fh ) {
        print $out_fh $_;
    }
}

close $out_fh;
```

#### output

```
Creating "A_1.txt"
Creating "Bxx_xx.txt"
Creating "P_b.txt"
Creating "1A_Z0.txt"
Creating "Z867.txt"
Creating "BWS.txt"
```

---

#### Update

Here's a new version of my code that complies with your revised specification. (Please don't do that.)

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

@ARGV = qw/ 4l.txt size_list.txt /;

my ( $input, $size_list ) = @ARGV;

my %sizes;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $size_list;
    while ( <$fh> ) {
        my ($file, $size) = split;
        $sizes{$file} = $size if defined $size;
    }
}


my $out_fh;
my @header;

while ( <> ) {

    if ( /^#/ ) {

        push @header, $_;

        if ( /Query:\s*(\S+)/ ) {

            my $id = $1;
            my $size = $sizes{$id};
            die qq{No size found for ID "$id"} unless defined $size;
            my $file = "$id.txt";

            print qq{Creating "$file"\n};

            open $out_fh, '>', $file;
            print $out_fh "$id\t$size\n";
        }

        if ( @header == 4 ) {
            print $out_fh @header;
            @header = ();
        }
    }
    elsif ( $out_fh ) {
        print $out_fh $_;
    }
}

close $out_fh if $out_fh;
```

Comment: Thank a lot. It works.

Comment: By the way, I lost some contents in my edited post which have the second part of the issue and so my code description is looking so different. Now where to edit now? Please help.

Comment: @perlbeginner: You had *"I have another file with all IDs and length. Example,"* is that what you mean? You gave an example of the contents but didn't describe their meaning or relevance to the question, so I deleted it. Why do you want that part in the question? Presumably `@sizeList` is something to do with that, but your code never puts anything into that array. By the way, please don't put `\t` in your data unless the file contains a backslash and a `t`. Putting the tabs into the data you post should be sufficient, but you may also say that the file is "tab-separated"

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Its my first day in stack overflow. I will correct all the mistakes I did. I edited the post again. "\t" means the tab in the file and @sizeList is array I get it from another file, which have IDs and some size. This should get matched with individual output file, and sitting on the first line of the output file. I hope this is clear.. Thanks.

Comment: @perlbeginner: Okay, I've changed all your `\t` sequences to real tab characters and removed every `\n` which I assume means a newline, and is there in the text already. It's best to think of Stack Overflow like a wiki rather than a forum, and every page is supposed to be problem and a set of solutions that could be useful to any number of other people. It's primary purpose is those other people, and not to get you the answer that you want.

Comment: @perlbeginner: You really shouldn't make substantial changes to your question like that. If you need to alter anything that makes any comments or answers invalid then you should *open a new question*. It's not fair to get me to rewrite my answer just because you got the question wrong in the first place. And you still don't show your complete code so I have to guess about a lot of things. It looks like you're either delcaring all your variables at the top of your program or you're not using `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'`. Both of those are a bad idea

Comment: These looked exactly like significant changes because of edit problem. But I didn't mean that way. Now I am clear. Thanks for all your suggestions. And, I declared all the variable before. I also used "use strict". I get both files using $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]. I copied only main block code and posted it.

Comment: @perlbeginner: You should also have `use warnings 'all'`. And it's wrong to declare everything in a block: you may as well just not declare them at all if you're going to do that. It's an old-fashioned C programming style, and it isn't even good in modern C. Variables should usually be declared where they're first mentioned, unless you need the scope to extend over a loop block, when they should be declared just before the loop

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. But there is a warning/error... "Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at multi2one2length.pl line 47, <> line 1."

Comment: This was corrected with an additional line "next if/^Query/;" right after opening the while (<>) loop. Because the input might have an additional line,"^Query" along with commented lines and other contents. Now it works.  Thanks once again!

Comment: @perlbeginner: I've updated my code. Please use that rather than your own fix

Comment: "elsif" update should go to the second version of your code, right? Because I am seeing this update in the first version of the code.

Comment: @perlbeginner: I'm sorry, yes, it should be in both versions. Fixed

Comment: Solved. Thanks again. J

Answer (score 0):

Code :

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $filename = "t1";#provide your input file name
open FH, $filename or die "Error\n";
my $prev_line;
while(my $line =<FH>)
{
        chomp($line);
        if($line =~ /#\sver/)
        {
                if($. != 1)
                {
                        close(FH2);
                }
                $prev_line =$line;
        }
        elsif($line =~ /#\sQuery:(.*)/)
        {
                my $id =$1;
                $id =~ s/\s//;
                print "$id\n";
                open FH2,">$id.txt" or die "Error";
                print FH2 "$prev_line\n$line\n";

        }
        else
        {
                print FH2 "$line\n";
        }

}
close(FH);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: We have no guarantee that the first line of comments starts with `# ver`, and `if ($. != 1) { close(FH2); }` appears to do nothing useful. It's also a bad example to use global file handles and the two-parameter form of `open`, and why not accept the file name on the command line?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works with a small correction "$line =~ /#\sQuery:\s(.*)/).

Comment: @perlbeginner: That should make no difference, as all spaces are stripped from `$id` before it is used

Comment: Ah yes, that space \s make no difference. # ver is the first commented line. It will be like that.

Comment: @Borodin - In the above script the file close is depend on `# ver` and I used  `if ($. != 1) { close(FH2); }` line to control the first line to close the file handler. I did not get your **It's also a bad example to use global file handles and the two-parameter form of open** point . can you please explain it.

Comment: The value of `$.` will only ever be 1 for the first line of input, which is before `FH2` has ever been opened.

Comment: As for *lexical file handles* and the *three-parameter form of `open`*, I'm amazed that you've done any significant programming in Perl without hearing of them, as they go along with `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` for good-practice Perl. Google will help you here.